# Why does Scala return Null for so many string operations?

Tags: scala

I'm just learning Scala 3, and I'm *trying* to write functional code, but I'm facing a lot of issues doing that, because so many methods return values that can be `Null`. This makes it hard to chain methods, since I would have to add so many Null checks. These issues only seem to happen in my IDE (and the compiler), running them in REPL produces correct types that can be chained.

A few examples:

```scala
val a = "hello world".split(" ")
// ^ type is: Array[String | Null] | Null

val b = "hello hello world".replaceAll("hello", "bye")
// ^ type is String | Null
```

Why is this happening? I'm looking at the Java source code of these methods, and the return types there don't suggest these methods would return `Null`.

Comment: You enabled the controversial explicit nulls feature, I would advise disabling that most **Scala** code simply assumes `null` doesn't exist and that feature is far from finished in a UX perspective.

Comment: That was it! I used a Giter8 template which seems to have this enabled by default.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez is the name of flag `-Yexplicit-nulls` for the controversial explicit nulls feature?

Comment: @RomanKazanovskyi yes, that one.